# In Visual Studio 2015 how to reverse/undo a commit in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a commit done by a developer in the remote Git repository hosted in VSTS that needs to be rolled back. From Visual Studio, without going to the command prompt or how to revert the commit?

> I want to undo the commit through Visual Studio without using a command prompt.

Comment: It would be better to apply a new commit that restored the repository to a previous state instead of retroactively rewriting history by "deleting" the last commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Also, why are you opposed to using the git command-line? It's the best way to become familiar with how git works - the GUI built-in to Visual Studio hides many important details that I personally feel are necessary for the inexperienced to be exposed to.

Comment: Please read the entire question before voting as dublicated. I want to undo the commit through Visual Studio without using a command prompt. @Dai

Comment: I already know how to do it from the command prompt, but I need to know how to do it inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the "Changes" tab in Team Explorer.  Select "Actions", then "View History" to view the history of the repository.  Identify the commit that you want to revert, right-click on it and select "Revert" from the context menu.

[image: Revert]

Comment: FWIW, http://gitforvisualstudio.com is some lovely training for Git in Visual Studio.  (I must admit that I'm biased, though.)

Comment: Thanks for that link, that will certainly come in handy for coworkers in the future! ;)

Comment: @EdwardThomson y'know what would be nice? If the context-menus for git operations had a tooltip that showed you the command-line equivalent of that menu option. So "Revert" would say "git revert {commit}`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Dai, I'll bring your suggestion to the team that works on the VS integration.

Comment: This doesn't work.  This makes a new commit that indicates that a commit was reverted.  this is not the same as undo-ing a commit.

Answer (score 22):

Selected answer is not correct.  In order to undo a commit you need to select reset, not revert.  Revvert will make a new commit with code contained in previous commit.  Where reset will actually delete the commits after the selected version.

Comment: The question literally asks how to _revert_ from the UI.  It doesn’t ask how to “undo”, which itself would require explanation.

Comment: The question also literally asks how to _undo_.  in fact it says the word _undo_ twice.  I believe the OP was just using a synonym for _undo_ when he says _revert_, and in fact does not mean specifically a _git_ _revert_ command.

Comment: And it uses the word revert once, and again in a comment that explicitly mentions the command line.  Your answer that explains the difference between revert and reset is useful, but your assumption that the OP wants to _do_ a reset doesn't have much basis.  Regardless, as it stands, this is a _comment_ on an existing answer, not an _answer_ to the question itself.  Showing how to both reset _and_ revert in Visual Studio would make this a very good answer to the question.

Comment: Regarding the difference between revert and reset, this answer is clearer than the one in MS documentation.

Comment: I wish your answer was the selected answer, now I've got an extra commit to somehow get rid of....

Comment: This gets my vote. Not only is it clear and concise, but I agree that the word Undo in the title and "rollback" in the body mean it is more likely the OP was asking about a reset. This answer does not actually say HOW to reset, so it is not a complete answer but it is the closer of the two answers IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem is VS 2019. Right-click reset, on the offending commit, didn't do anything in either --hard or --mixed modes.

What did work was right-click on the **previous commit**, and then select *Reset->Keep Changes (--mixed)*. After that my mistaken commit was undone as if it had never been, and I could make the commit had I intended to make.

Maybe this is obvious to people who understand git, but no amount of searching showed me this.